# Visual studio - IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, linq-to-sql, datatable, submitchanges

I'm trying to add records to a local database using Visual Studio 2015 and `linq to sql` commands, but I get an error `IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF`.

I'm not inserting a value for the primary key and `Identity Specification` is set to `True`.
This is the generated script file:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MONTE_CARLO] (
    [PK]        INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ID]        INT             NOT NULL,
    [BOOK_COMP] NCHAR (10)      NOT NULL,
    [GREEK]     NCHAR (10)      NOT NULL,
    [DP1]       DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [DP2]       DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [DP3]       DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [DP4]       DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [DP5]       DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [DP6]       DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [DP7]       DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [DP8]       DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [DP9]       DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [DP10]      DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [DP11]      DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [DP12]      DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [DP13]      DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [DP14]      DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [DP15]      DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [DP16]      DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [DP17]      DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [DP18]      DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [DP19]      DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [DP20]      DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [DP21]      DECIMAL (18, 6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MONTE_CARLO] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PK] ASC)
);
```

This is the code to update the datatable. I'm passing a dictionary (`dct`)to the function which handles the updating.

```
Dim mcQuery = From updtMC In DATA.MONTE_CARLOs        'ID exists so update data
                          Where updtMC.ID = CStr(dct("ID")) And updtMC.BOOK_COMP = CStr(dct("BOOK_COMP")) And updtMC.GREEK = CStr(dct("GREEK"))
                          Select updtMC
            For Each updtMC As MONTE_CARLO In mcQuery

                updtMC.ID = dct("ID")
                updtMC.BOOK_COMP = dct("BOOK_COMP")
                updtMC.GREEK = dct("GREEK")
                updtMC.DP1 = dct("DP1")
                updtMC.DP2 = dct("DP2")
                updtMC.DP3 = dct("DP3")
                updtMC.DP4 = dct("DP4")
                updtMC.DP5 = dct("DP5")
                updtMC.DP6 = dct("DP6")
                updtMC.DP7 = dct("DP7")
                updtMC.DP8 = dct("DP8")
                updtMC.DP9 = dct("DP9")
                updtMC.DP10 = dct("DP10")
                updtMC.DP11 = dct("DP11")
                updtMC.DP12 = dct("DP12")
                updtMC.DP13 = dct("DP13")
                updtMC.DP14 = dct("DP14")
                updtMC.DP15 = dct("DP15")
                updtMC.DP16 = dct("DP16")
                updtMC.DP17 = dct("DP17")
                updtMC.DP18 = dct("DP18")
                updtMC.DP19 = dct("DP19")
                updtMC.DP20 = dct("DP20")
                updtMC.DP21 = dct("DP21")
            Next
        End If

        DATA.SubmitChanges()
```

[image: Monte_Carlo settings]

linq to sql files for Monte_Carlo:

```
<Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name:="dbo.MONTE_CARLO")>  _
Partial Public Class MONTE_CARLO
    Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private Shared emptyChangingEventArgs As PropertyChangingEventArgs = New PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty)

    Private _PK As Integer

    Private _ID As Integer

    Private _BOOK_COMP As String

    Private _GREEK As String

    Private _DP1 As Decimal

    Private _DP2 As Decimal

    Private _DP3 As Decimal

    Private _DP4 As Decimal

    Private _DP5 As Decimal

    Private _DP6 As Decimal

    Private _DP7 As Decimal

    Private _DP8 As Decimal

    Private _DP9 As Decimal

    Private _DP10 As Decimal

    Private _DP11 As Decimal

    Private _DP12 As Decimal

    Private _DP13 As Decimal

    Private _DP14 As Decimal

    Private _DP15 As Decimal

    Private _DP16 As Decimal

    Private _DP17 As Decimal

    Private _DP18 As Decimal

    Private _DP19 As Decimal

    Private _DP20 As Decimal

    Private _DP21 As Decimal

    Private _BOOK As EntityRef(Of BOOK)
```

Comment: shoq the linq where you add the records

Comment: Tks for the response...I've edited the question to show the code to add records.

Comment: Can you also show class MONTE_CARLOs please?

Comment: ok but I'm not sure what you mean, where will I find the class for the datatable ``MONTE_CARLO``?

Comment: right-click on MONTE_CARLO -> Go to definition

Comment: Alex I've added a screenshot of the datatable settings to the question. When I right clicked on the table I could only see ``open table definition``. Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: No I mean the LinqToSql class. There must be a class in your `lnqPOLARIS.dbml` file which represents the MONTE_CARLO table. I need the code behind to help you. There should be an property like `<Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage:="_PK", AutoSync:=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType:="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey:=true, IsDbGenerated:=true)>  _
 Public Property PK() As Integer`

Comment: ok i know what you mean, I just can't find it. If I right click on ``lnqPolaris.dbml`` in solution explorer I can open a window to view code, but there is no code there like what you are looking for. Where else should I look?

Comment: In Project Explorer click `Show all files` -> Expand `lnqPOLARIS.dbml` -> expand `lnqPOLARIS.designer.vb` -> double-click `MONTE_CARLO`

Comment: tks I found it and added the code to the bottom of the question.

Comment: Unless you *specify* a different key, Linq to SQL assumes the key is `ID`. Check your mapping, not the database. Far better is to use ID as your primary key though - *anyone* looking at the schema will assume a column named ID is the actual .... identifier for the entity. Why do you define a separate column as Identity anyway?

Comment: tks, to you and shukri, I'll try changing ID to another name and see if it helps. ID maps to another table and to keep the code simple for now I made ID another data column, not the primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on naming conventions in entity framework columns with name Id are considered as Id, probably you are having this problem. Try to change the name of field ID.

Comment: Actually, the OP should rename PK to ID. Anyone looking at the schema will assume *this* is the unique identifier, not another field named PK